# MVC-Viewmodel and LINQ, Insert value into a table and the value gets tagged by two other values in two other tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, mvvm

I am using MVC-Viewmodel with repository pattern with EF on my project.

I have 3 tables, Question, CoreValue, SubjectType.
SubjectType and CoreValue are many to many associated with Question and these two tables are not suppose to get any new values, but users can create questions so Question table will get new data when a user creates it. I use two dropdownlists for CoreValue and SubjectType so that the user can choose a CoreValue and a SubjectType when they create a Question.

Here is my HTTPGET controller action:

```
    // GET: /Admin/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {

    CoreValueRepository Crep = new CoreValueRepository();
    SubjectTypeRepository Srep = new SubjectTypeRepository();

        CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
        List<SubjectType> subjectypes = Srep.getall();
        List<CoreValue> corevalues = Crep.getall();
        model.SubjectTypes = new SelectList(subjectypes, "SID", "Sname");
        model.CoreValues = new SelectList(corevalues, "CID", "Cname");

        return View(model);

    }
```

And here is my Viewmodel:

public class CreateViewModel
{

```
public string QuestionText { get; set; }
public string Sname { get; set; }
public string Cname { get; set; }

public SelectList SubjectTypes { get; set; }
public SelectList CoreValues { get; set; }
```

}

I use Repository for CRUD operations and viewmodels for handling data in UI.

Now I have to code the HTTPPOST Action Create in my controller for inserting Question data to my database, and the questions need to be tagged with CoreValue ID and SubjectType ID. So I was thinkin about to start coding the HTTPOST action Create, and I was wondering if someone could help me out with this.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i would handle it :

In your ViewModel, replace :

```
public class CreateViewModel {

public string QuestionText { get; set; }
public string Sname { get; set; }
public string Cname { get; set; }

public int SubjectTypesID { get; set; }
public int CoreValuesID { get; set; }
}
```

In your HTTPGET put your list in Viewbags :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

    CoreValueRepository Crep = new CoreValueRepository();
    SubjectTypeRepository Srep = new SubjectTypeRepository();

    CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
    ViewBag.SubjectTypes = Srep.getall();
    ViewBag.CoreValues = Crep.getall();

    return View(model);

}
```

To use the viewbag in your view you can use this :

```
@Html.DropDownList("SubjectTypesID ", new SelectList(ViewBag.SubjectTypes as  System.Collections.IEnumerable, "SID", "Sname", Model.SubjectTypesID ))

@Html.DropDownList("CoreValuesID ", new SelectList(ViewBag.CoreValues as  System.Collections.IEnumerable, "CID", "Cname", Model.CoreValuesID ))
```

Your HTTPOST :

```
[HTTPOST]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
{
    //Now with your model you have the Id of CoreValue and SubjectType
    //You could do
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
   QuestionRep.Add(model);
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }


   return View(model);
}
```

Hope this can help you :)

Edit :

in my repository I do :

```
 public void Add(Model.Models.LabExam.Examen entity)
    {
        using (var context = new PDSIDataContext())
        {
            var exam = BindModelExamenToRepExamen(entity);
            context.Examen.InsertOnSubmit(exam);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Binding methods (Repository.Examen represents my table, Repository is my project where I have a .dbml to represent my DB):

```
     private static Repository.Examen BindModelExamenToRepExamen(Model.Models.LabExam.Examen modelExamen)
    {
        return new Repository.Examen
        {
            ID_Examen = modelExamen.ID,
            ID_Examen_Type = modelExamen.ID_Examen_Type,
            Date_Prescription = modelExamen.Date_Prescription,
            Realise_Le = modelExamen.Realise_Le,
            Statut = modelExamen.Statut,
            Fait = modelExamen.Fait,
            ID_Examen_Sous_Type = modelExamen.ID_Examen_Sous_Type,
            ID_Examen_Sous_Sous_Type = modelExamen.ID_Examen_Sous_Sous_Type,
            ID_Patient = modelExamen.ID_Patient,
            Commentaires = modelExamen.Commentaires
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! Do you have any idea how I can do my HTTPPOST with the code I have right now?

Comment: Well, if you keep the selectList in your viewmodel, I don't know if you will have access to the selectedValue of the seleclist from the viewmodel you will have in your HTTPOST. That why I gave you another way of doing it ^^. In the httpost, the parameter model will contain all the info that he user entered, so you just have to pass this paramter to your repository to save it.

Comment: Okey I tried with the viewbag  var newQuestion = question(); newQuestion.SubjectTypeId = model.SubjectTypeID; Aint working beacuse newQuestion is a question class and I can only choose the values that Question table has, not subjectTypes ID. :S

Comment: I edited my code. In your repository, just create a new object that has the same type as your database table then you just have to bind the model attributes to your new object. I edited again my answer to show you how I do it in my repository ^^